# How Cheap AC Clamp Meter Reading on DC Current?

Tags: multimeter

Harbor Freight's cheap CEN-TECH clamp meter does register on DC wires.  For example, 12V powering an inverter at about 10 amps current DC from the battery to the inverter reads +1.68 amp then +1.52 amp turned the opposite direction.  The reading matched on both positive and negative wires, each reading 180° from the other as expected.

Might this reading be reliably proportionate to the actual 10 amp current?  I did not expect this meter to read anything on DC current.  Perhaps it measures Hall effect?

Here is the meter: [Harbor freight cheap AC clamp meter](http://www.harborfreight.com/digital-clamp-meter-96308.html)

Comment: *"a 12 line powering an inverter"* Huh?  Clean up the gibberish.  We do engineering here, not hand waving.  It's not clear what you are talking about.

Comment: That is, from context, a DC-to-AC power converter, not a small triangular symbol with a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a DC supply is powering an AC inverter, the current tends to have an entirely logical 60 or 50 (or 400 if you are one of those oddballs) Hz form (0-to-max) that matches the inverter's output power. (120-100 Hz Half-sine, more correctly - looks like a rectified sine wave, pretty much.)

It's still direct current (it does not change direction), but it's direct **pulsating** current, not direct **constant** current. A pulsating current will result in pulsating/changing magnetic fields. The pulse will be right in the sweet spot for a meter intended to read 50-60 Hz AC to pick up...

If you power a constant current DC load (like an automotive headlamp), you will very likely see "nothing" on your AC-Only clamp-on meter. It would terribly unlikely for a Hall effect sensor to find its way into a *horrible fright* AC-only meter, which will be built to the absolute lowest cost.

Comment: @STWilson to clarify the last paragraph, there *are* clamp meters capailable of measuring DC current: they measure the magnetic field strenght induced within a toroidal core (that would be the clamp) with a linear hall effect sensor. Your crappy meter isn't part of that club.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  I didn't consider the DC current was pulsing, therefore was perplexed why the meter read anything at all.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

The hand-held clamp meter that you listed measures AC current. This means it will ignore DC current. Therefore, the conclusion I can make is that although the wires are carrying a DC current, there is also a superimposed AC current riding on top of the DC current.

Your meter will attempt to read that superimposed AC current. I say "attempt" because it may be a high frequency AC current (not 50 or 60 Hz) and the measurement accuracy of the meter at higher frequencies may be poor. Read the data sheet.